# Python Tkinter loop in a loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

What I am attempting to do is run another file (file1 process) , and while that file is running  I want to check the local directory for existence of a file. If the file doesn't exist then everything keeps running and check again in 30 seconds. If the file does exist I want to print the contents to a label and stop the file1 process.

My code below causes Tkinter to erase all of its  labels. Where am I going wrong ?

```
def turnOn():
global proc
if proc is None:
    print('Starting Beacon')
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "/home/pi/FLBeacon/FLBeaconout.py"])
    label1 = Label(window,text ="Beacon is Running")
    label1.configure(bg='green')
    label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
    global  label2
    label2 = Label(window,text = full_message)
    label2.configure(bg='green')
    label2.place(x=50, y=90, width=550)
    filelist = ['FLBeaconRecieved.txt']
    while True:
        list1 = []
        for file in filelist:
            list1.append(os.path.isfile(file))

        if all(list1):
           #all elements are true
           file = open("FLBeaconRecieved.txt")
           data = file.read()
           file.close()
           Results = Label(window, text = data)
           Results.place(x = 50, y = 350)
           print('Beacon Stopped')
           proc.terminate()
           proc = None
           label1 = Label(window,text = "Beacon is not running")
           label1.configure(bg='red')
           label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
           label2.destroy()
           break
        else:
          time.sleep(30)
          print("there is no file")




on = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text = "Start Beacon", width=15, pady=5, command = turnOn)
off = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text = "Stop Beacon", width=15, pady=5, command = turnOff)
on.place(x=215,y=300)
 off.place(x=380,y=300)


def stop():
   window.destroy()
   #Top.destroy()

b = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text="Update Beacon", width=15, pady=5, command=enter)
b.place(x=50,y=300)
b = Button(window, borderwidth=2, text="Exit", width=12, pady=5, command = combine_funcs(turnOff, stop))
b.place(x=250,y=550)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: instead of `while True` and `sleep()` use `root.after( miliseconds, function_name_without_() )` to run function periodically. it will not block `mainloop()`. You can find many examples with `after()` - ie. how to display current time.

Comment: instead of `combine_funcs(turnOff, stop)` you could put `turnOff()` inside `def stop():` - it would be more readable.

Comment: thanks furas that after function did the trick! I have it functioning now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to remove the while loop and move the after() statement to the else: now it works...this particular code I am sure doesn't work but it explains the concept.

```
def turnOn():
  global proc
   if proc is None:
window.after(50000,file_chk)
print('Starting Beacon')
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "/home/pi/FLBeacon/FLBeaconout.py"])
label1 = Label(window,text ="Beacon is Running")
label1.configure(bg='green')
label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
global  label2
label2 = Label(window,text = full_message)
label2.configure(bg='green')
label2.place(x=50, y=90, width=550)

def file_chk():
   filelist = ['FLBeaconRecieved.txt']

   list1 = []
   for file in filelist:
   list1.append(os.path.isfile(file))

    if all(list1):
       #all elements are true
       print("file has been found")
       file = open("FLBeaconRecieved.txt")
       data = file.read()
       file.close()
       Results = Label(window, text = data)
       Results.place(x = 50, y = 350)
       turnOff() 
       label1 = Label(window,text = "Beacon is not running")
       label1.configure(bg='red')
       label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
       label2.destroy()
       return
    else:
      print("there is no file")
       window.after(50000,file_chk)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to function .....

```
def turnOn():
 global proc
  if proc is None:
    window.after(50000,file_chk)
    print('Starting Beacon')
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "/home/pi/FLBeacon/FLBeaconout.py"])
    label1 = Label(window,text ="Beacon is Running")
    label1.configure(bg='green')
    label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
    global  label2
    label2 = Label(window,text = full_message)
    label2.configure(bg='green')
    label2.place(x=50, y=90, width=550)

def file_chk():
    filelist = ['FLBeaconRecieved.txt']
    while True:
        list1 = []
        for file in filelist:
            list1.append(os.path.isfile(file))

        if all(list1):
           #all elements are true
           print("file has been found")
           file = open("FLBeaconRecieved.txt")
           data = file.read()
           file.close()
           Results = Label(window, text = data)
           Results.place(x = 50, y = 350)
           turnOff() 
           label1 = Label(window,text = "Beacon is not running")
           label1.configure(bg='red')
           label1.place(x= 350, y=10, width=150)
           label2.destroy()
           return
        else:
          print("there is no file")
          time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Please select this as the answer, if it resolved your issue.